# VB.NET Join Error Conversion from String is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I have absolutely no idea why I am getting this error. The are no zero length strings in this array.

Here are screenshots. As you can see, it shows the entire string array. The String.Join function is failing no matter what. There are no integers or zero-length strings involved. I am absolutely stumped.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEu0P.jpg

Answer: Ramankingdom nailed it. Simple cut and paste and it worked. I guess I was just up too later. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: trying with only vbCrLf instead of Chr(vbCrLf).ToString maybe? If you just want to append vbCrLf, why not ...& vbCrLr or ...+= vbCrLf ?

Comment: Images of code don't cut it here.  Post your code as well formatted text in the body of your question.

Comment: You are not using the `Join` method that you think you are using. As you type that statement, you should see that intellisense is telling you that an Integer is expected where you typed `vbCrLf`. You probably intended to use `String.Join`.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me Visual Basic Code. If it is VB.NET Code
use instead

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, _contents)
```

Comment: `If it is VB.NET Code` - No one stated otherwise?